# Mantener posición elemento al redimensionar página

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una imagen con algunos elementos sobre ella. Resulta que cuando redimensiono la pantalla quiero que estos elementos continúen en la posición que deben estar respecto a la imagen. He intentado de una forma pero no me ha funcionado. A ver si alguien pudiera decirme como podría hacerlo

```
    function posicionesJugadores(tipoDeporte){
    //Calculamos el ancho y alto de la pantalla por defecto para cuando hagamos resize()
    var xTabDefecto = $('#cancha').width();
    var yTabDefecto= $('#cancha').height();
    //Según el tipo de deporte, aparecerán unas posiciones en el campo u otras
    switch(tipoDeporte){
            case 'baloncesto':
                //creamos una lista posicion con el nombre de la posición y sus posiciones x,y
                var posicionDeporte = [
                    {posicion: 'pivotA',posX: 250, posY: 585}, 
                    {posicion: 'aleroA', posX: 320, posY: 380},
                    {posicion: 'alaPivotA', posX: 420,posY: 400},
                    {posicion: 'escoltaA',posX: 400,posY: 600},
                    {posicion: 'baseA',posX: 530,posY: 480},
                    {posicion: 'pivotB',posX: 1150, posY: 585}, 
                    {posicion: 'aleroB', posX: 1090,posY: 380},
                    {posicion: 'alaPivotB', posX: 990, posY: 400},
                    {posicion: 'escoltaB',posX: 1005,posY: 600},
                    {posicion: 'baseB',posX: 880,posY: 480}];

                    //Añadimos cada posición en el campo según posX y posY
                    for(var posicionJugador of posicionDeporte){
                        $('#cancha').append('<div id='+posicionJugador.posicion+' class="posicion_jugador"></div>');
                        $('#'+posicionJugador.posicion+'').offset({left: posicionJugador.posX, top: posicionJugador.posY});
                    }
            break;    
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var xTabActual = $('#cancha').width();
        var yTabActual = $('#cancha').height();

        for(var posicionJugador of posicionDeporte){
            var proporcionX = posicionJugador.posX / xTabDefecto;
            var proporcionY = posicionJugador.posY / yTabDefecto;
            $('#'+posicionJugador.posicion+'').offset({left: xTabActual*proporcionX, top: yTabActual*proporcionY});
        }
    })
};
```

Lo que hago es crear una lista de las posiciones por defecto, también saco el tamaño de la pantalla por defecto y el tamaño de la pantalla actual cuando hago `resize()` para luego crear una proporción de estos con la posición, pero no me funciona como esperaba.

[image: posiciones por defecto]

[image: posiciones actuales]

En la primera imagen aparecen las posiciones en su posición por defecto, y en la segunda aparecen las posiciones mal puestas cuando redimensiono. gracias de antemano

Comment: Deberías calcular la proporción respecto al tamaño de la ventana y no a la posición del jugador.

Comment: mide en porcentajes las posiciones y colocas position relative al tablero y position absolute a las fichas y con jquery o javascript las mueves tambien en porcentajes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te faltó proporcionar información y voy a tener que asumir algunas cosas, como HTML, CSS y, **lo más importante**, las medidas por defecto de la cancha, porque es de aquí donde se debe partir para calcular la posición de los jugadores.

En CSS asigné el ancho al 100% (ya sea de la pantalla o del contenedor), para que se adapte, independientemente del tamaño de pantalla original o al redimensionar.

Agregué la variable `ratio` para guardar ahí la proporción de la cancha actual respecto al ancho por defecto: *proporción = ancho_actual / ancho_por_defecto*

Tanto al generar la cancha (carga de página), como al redimensionar pantalla, debes obtener la proporción, ajustar la altura de la cancha y multiplicar la posición de los jugadores (horizontal y vertical) por la proporción.

**Nota:** Hice una función para crear los jugadores, de forma que te pueda servir para otros deportes.

**Nota 2:** Probablemente convenga adaptar el tamaño de *los jugadores* también, para que no se vean puntos muy pequeños cuando la cancha es grande ni puntos muy grandes cuando la cancha se reduce.

```js
// Establecer medidas por defecto de cancha
let canchaDefaultW = 1400; // width
let canchaDefaultH = 1000;  // height
// Establecer proporción inicial
let ratio = 1;
let cancha = $('#cancha');

               let posicionDeporte = [
                    {posicion: 'pivotA',posX: 250, posY: 585}, 
                    {posicion: 'aleroA', posX: 320, posY: 380},
                    {posicion: 'alaPivotA', posX: 420,posY: 400},
                    {posicion: 'escoltaA',posX: 400,posY: 600},
                    {posicion: 'baseA',posX: 530,posY: 480},
                    {posicion: 'pivotB',posX: 1150, posY: 585}, 
                    {posicion: 'aleroB', posX: 1090,posY: 380},
                    {posicion: 'alaPivotB', posX: 990, posY: 400},
                    {posicion: 'escoltaB',posX: 1005,posY: 600},
                    {posicion: 'baseB',posX: 880,posY: 480}
               ];

function setCancha() {
    // Obtener proporción
    ratio = $(cancha).width() / canchaDefaultW;
    // Ajustar altura de cancha de acuerdo a proporción
    $(cancha).height(parseInt(canchaDefaultH * ratio));

}
function drawPlayers(players) {
    //Añadimos cada posición en el campo según posX y posY
    for(var posicionJugador of players){
        $('#cancha').append('<div id='+posicionJugador.posicion+' class="posicion_jugador"></div>');
        $('#'+posicionJugador.posicion+'').offset({left: parseInt(posicionJugador.posX * ratio), top: parseInt(posicionJugador.posY * ratio)});
    }
}
$(window).resize(function(){
    // Actualizar medidas de cancha y obtener proporción
    setCancha();
    // Mover jugadores al cambiar tamaño de pantalla
    for(var posicionJugador of posicionDeporte){
        $('#'+posicionJugador.posicion+'').offset({left: parseInt(posicionJugador.posX * ratio), top: parseInt(posicionJugador.posY * ratio)});
    }
});
// Obtener datos para posicionar desde que carga la página
setCancha();
drawPlayers(posicionDeporte);
```

```css
#cancha {
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
    background:#080;
}

.posicion_jugador {
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cancha"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Intenta asignadole al tablero `position:relative` y a los jugadores `position:absolute`.

Por ejemplo aquí el tablero con 400x200 pixeles que puedes editar. Siempre y cuando le apliques dimenciones correctas, veras como los jugadores mantienen su posición relativa al tablero:

```js
function redimencionar()
{
  var width = document.getElementById("w").value;
  var height = document.getElementById("h").value;
  debugger;
  document.getElementById("tablero").style.width = width + "px";
  document.getElementById("tablero").style.height = height + "px";
  
}
```

```css
#tablero{
  position:relative;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:green;
}

#tablero .player{
  position:absolute;
  background:white;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
}
#tablero #p1{ left:20%; top:10%}
#tablero #p2{ left:45%; top:50%}
#tablero #p3{ left:3%; top:40%}
```

```html
Ancho <input type="text" placeholder="ancho" id="w"/>, Alto:
<input type="text" placeholder="alto" id="h"/>
<br>
<button onclick="redimencionar()">Redimencionar</button>
</br>
<div id="tablero">
  <div class="player" id="p1"></div>
  <div class="player" id="p2"></div>
  <div class="player" id="p3"></div>
</div>
```

Esto es debido a que cuando los elementos con `posicion:absolute` se encuentran dentro de un elemento `position:relative`, estos tomaran al contenedor como referencia para calcular su posicion.
Esto tambien te afectara a que tendras que calcular la posicion del jugador siempre en base al contedor(tablero) para poder asinarle las posiciones correctas.

Ten encuenta que esto funciona siempre y cuando la posición de los jugadores sean por porcentajes. Si se lo aplicas en pixeles, entonces los jugadores se pasaran fuera de su contenedor.